# fractional imaginary calculation

Tags: complex-numbers, matlab, fractional-part

Assume $j=\sqrt{-1}$, to calculate $(-3.1416j)^{0.5}$ in Matlab, I type

`(j*-3.1416)^0.5` and it gives me the result: `1.2533 - 1.2533i`.

However, if I calculate it in another way $(-3.1416j)^{0.5}=(-1)^{0.5}*j^{0.5}*(3.1416)^{0.5}$, i.e.,

`(-1)^0.5*j^0.5*(3.1416)^0.5` and it gives me: `-1.2533 + 1.2533i`, which is the opposite of the first result.

Why and what's wrong here? How to solve this problem to get a consistent result? Just add a minus sign `-(-1)^0.5*j^0.5*(3.1416)^0.5`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Every non-zero complex number has two square roots

Comment: It is possible for $\sqrt{ab} \neq \sqrt{a}\times \sqrt{b}$ when at least one of $a,b$ is not a positive real number.  Consider the case where $a=b=-1$

Comment: if you leave out the fractional part, using $3$ instead of $3.1416$, do you still get two different answers?

Answer (score 2):

Every non-zero complex number has two square roots:  if $w^2=z$, then $(-w)^2=z$ too.

You found one square root one way, and one the other.  (The program gives you only one each time.)

Comment: in other words, nothing is really wrong here, just it's confusing there is not a unique answer

Comment: How can I get a unique answer because it's numerical calculation?

Comment: You’d have to say you want the result in a particular half plane or something like that

Comment: Note:  my answer above was posted before the question was edited